# How to auto-format phone number using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, angular6

In Angular I set mobile number as (888)8888-888 and write maxlength is 13 and keypress event for autoformatting the pattern to automatically press bracket and dash, but in mobile autoformat is not working: it take 13 number as mobile number.

```
<ion-label stacked>MOBILE (OPTIONAL)</ion-label>
<ion-input name="mobile1" placeholder="(888)888-8888" maxlength="13" class="hoverBorder"
   (keypress)="checkMobileLength($event.target.value,'buyer')" type="text" formControlName="mobile1"
   [class.invalid]="!signupBuyer.controls.mobile1.valid && (signupBuyer.controls.mobile1.dirty || submitAttempt)">
</ion-input>

checkMobileLength(val, data) {
   if (data == 'buyer') {
      if (val.length == 3) {
         this.signupBuyer.controls.mobile1.setValue('(' + val + ')')
      } if (val.length == 8) {
         this.signupBuyer.controls.mobile1.setValue(val + '-')
      }
   } else if (data == 'agent') {
      if (val.length == 3) {
         this.signup1.controls.mobile1.setValue('(' + val + ')')
      } if (val.length == 8) {
         this.signup1.controls.mobile1.setValue(val + '-')
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Urmila please add a better explanation of what your code is supposed to do as well as the steps you have taken to try to troubleshoot the issue! Welcome to SO!

Comment: I added some punctuations and changed the language a tiny bit, hopefully not changing the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
(ionChange) instead of  (keypress)